# Paradoxical behaviour of math.nan when combined with the 'in' operator

Tags: python

I have the following lines of code:

```
import math as mt

...
...
...

        if mt.isnan (coord0):
            print (111111, coord0, type (coord0), coord0 in (None, mt.nan))
            print (222222, mt.nan, type (mt.nan), mt.nan in (None, mt.nan))
```

It prints:

```
111111 nan <class 'float'> False
222222 nan <class 'float'> True
```

I am baffled...
Any explanation?

Python 3.6.0, Windows 10

I have a rock solid confidence in the quality of the Python interpreter...
And I know, whenever it seems the computer makes a mistake, it's actually me being mistaken...
So what am I missing?

[EDIT]

(In reaction to @COLDSPEED)

Indeed the ID's are different:

```
print (111111, coord0, type (coord0), id (coord0), coord0 in (None, mt.nan))
print (222222, mt.nan, type (mt.nan), id (mt.nan), mt.nan in (None, mt.nan))
```

Prints:

```
111111 nan <class 'float'> 2149940586968 False
222222 nan <class 'float'> 2151724423496 True
```

Maybe there's a good reason whey nan isn't a true singleton. But I do not yet get it. This behavior is rather error prone in my view.

[EDIT2]

(In reaction to @Sven Marnach)

Carefully reading the answer of @Sven Marnach makes it understandable to me. It is indeed a compromise of the kind one encounters when designing things.

Still the ice is thin:

Having `a in (b,)` return `True` if `id (a) == id (b)` seems to be at odds with the IEEE-754 standard that `nan` should be unequal to `nan`.

The conclusion would have to be that while `a` is in an aggregate, at the same time it isn't, because the thing in the aggregate, namely `b` has to be considered unequal to `a` by IEEE standards.

Think I'll use `isnan` from now on...

Comment: I thought it was because `math.nan != math.nan`, but `math.nan in [math.nan]` returns `True`. Guess coldspeed is likely correct.

Comment: (Reposting my comment, accidentally deleted) I think the checking is being done on the ID. The nan in coord0 has a different ID than the mt.nan constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you see is an artefact of an optimization for the `in` operator in Python and the fact that `nan` compares unequal to itself, as required by the IEEE-754 standard.

The `in` operator in Python returns whether any element in the iterator is equal to the element you are looking for.  The expression `x in it` essentially evaluates to `any(x == y for y in it)`, except that an additional optimization is applied by CPython: to avoid having to call `__eq__` on each element, the interpreter first checks whether `x` and `y` are the same objects, in which case it immediately returns `True`.

This optimization is fine for almost all objects.  After all, it's one of the basic properties of equality that every object compares equal to itself.  However, the IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers requires that `nan != nan`, so NaN breaks this assumption.  This results in the odd behaviour you see:  if one `nan` happens to be the *same object* as a `nan` in the iterator, the above-mentioned optimization results in the `in` operator returning `True`.  However, if the `nan` in the iterator isn't the same object, Python falls back to `__eq__()`, and you get `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, how NaN is implemented is a total clowntown. This is what happens when you override `__eq__` without thinking about consequences:

```
>>> n1 = math.nan
>>> n2 = math.nan
>>> id(n1) == id(n2)
True
>>> n1 == n2
False
```

Just use `isNan` end let them handle all that mess.